# Use Chrome Extension on site created by extension?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I am currently tinkering with [Yomichan](https://github.com/FooSoft/yomichan), an extension that can parse Japanese in the browser with different dictionaries. I added a functionality where you can parse subtitles (and later books and other text) and then get some information from them. This works just fine when I use Yomichan's parser on the backend.

My problem is, I can't use Yomichan's parser on sites directly (you can usually hold Shift and Yomichan parses the text under your mouse and shows a popup with word definitions) that the extension created itself, so that begin with "chrome-extension://". I tried to add permission for those sites, but [The official google site about extension permissions](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/mv3/match_patterns/) states that using chrome-extension:// is forbidden. I presume this is for security reasons, but does this mean that there is no possibility for me to use the popup-dictionary on a site the extension opened itself?

Thanks in advance!